# With the EntityDataSource, where does the "it" come from?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, gridview, webforms

So, I'm doing some work with `ASP.NET` and `Entity Framework 6` using `WebForms`.

I setup a simple GridView bound to an EntityDataSource.  I've also setup a little textbox that filters my result set.

Works pretty well.  I've pulled the example from tutorials online but what I don't seem to get is where the `it` piece of the `Where` clause is coming from?  It looks like pure LINQ to me (which I have some experience in).

Here is an example of my EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource
    ID="TrailerDataSource"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=DBContext"
    DefaultContainerName="DBContext"
    EnableFlattening="False"
    EntitySetName="Trailers"
    EntityTypeFilter="Trailer"
    EnableInsert="True"
    EnableUpdate="True"
    Where="it.TrailerNumber LIKE '%' + @TrailerNumber + '%'">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter
                ControlID="tbTrailerNumberFilter"
                DbType="String"
                DefaultValue="%"
                Name="TrailerNumber"
                PropertyName="Text" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I know this is a silly question, but try Googling for "it".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "it" element is the current "item" , it comes from Dynamic Linq